# Show the following series converges to $\frac{1}{e}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\tau \in \mathbb{N} $ whereas $\tau$ fulfils the following condition: 
$$ \sum_{i= \tau}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} \lt 1\le \sum_{i=\tau-1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i}$$

Prove that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\tau-1}{n}\sum_{j=\tau-1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j} = \frac{1}{e}$$

I did some previous work on it but it does not seem right to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the first equation, the terms of the sum are missing. Should they be $\frac{1}{i}$?

Comment: Sorry, I correct this in a sec. It should be $\frac{1}{\tau}$.

Comment: Check your notation again.  A sum over $i$, but the summand does not involve $i$?

Comment: I had the same doubt but this actually what is being said in the lecture notes.

Comment: @Gedgar: I think it really is a mistake in the lecture notes. I followed Daniels suggestion and replaced $\frac{1}{\tau}$ with $\frac{1}{\i}$. It seems to work with this assumption. I edit my solution here once I worked it out.

Comment: So, it is up to you to check with the source, and not up to us to guess what was meant.

Comment: You are right. Apologies for the confusion. I will discuss the mistake with my lecturer on tuesday.